# Convert text blob to nvarchar from Firebird to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, firebird, openquery

I am using `SQL Server` and have got a `Firebird` database as a linked server in my SQL Server.

I am trying to do an `OPENQUERY` to import data from the `Firebird` db;

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Workbench, 'SELECT * FROM table_name')
```

and am getting the following error.

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Workbench" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].NOTES" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Workbench".
```

The data type `NOTES` field in the `Firebird` db is `blob`. If  I omit the field `NOTES` the query executes and the results are imported correct.

But I need the information in the `NOTES` field and am looking for a way to `type cast` the blob field to `nvarchar`. I believe that this should be done within the `Openquery` (i.e. in the Firebird side of the query).

Could somebody suggest a pure `SQL` solution to convert `blob` to `nvarchar` in `Firebird` Please?

Comment: What is the character set of the text blob, and what is your connection character set?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thank you for your reply Mark.. Sorry but how could I check that character set? Could you tell me please??

Comment: For the blob character set: look at the DDL of the table, for the connection character set: look at the connection string of your ODBC datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but maybe it can help someone...

You can cast the blob to a varchar by this statement:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(BlobColumn FROM 1 FOR 32000) AS VARCHAR(32000)) AS NewBlobColumn
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Then you can use this in the OPENQUERY-Statement

Answer (score 1):

look at Microsoft KB
[OLE DB conversion errors may occur](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813524)

if this not work for you
than is your field NOTES big text or reletive small < 32767 chars?
[32767 i got from here - limitations in Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/)
If it is small - try to cast it to varchar

```
SELECT CAST(NOTES AS VARCHAR(32767)), other fields FROM TABLE_NAME
```

First try with smallest notes and smaller varchar cast - and look if it work
If yes than maybe - problem is with blob at all

Answer (score 0):

I believe Firebird `blob` is `image` data type in MS SQL, so casting to `varbinary` and then to `varchar` should help. Have you tried this?

```
select cast(cast(NOTES as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) from openquery(Workbench,'select * from table_name')
```

Hope that helps.